# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid handle

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, sqlexception, dbconnection

I'm trying to teach myself how to connect to a msaccess database in java.
I have set up a class to access the database as follows

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public abstract class AccessDBConnect2 {
    public static Connection connect(){
        String fileName = "C:/Users/Bridget/Documents/EmployeeSys.accdb";
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions    ...
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("A problem accessing the database");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { if(con!=null) {con.close();} } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        return con;
    }
public static void closeConnection(Connection conn){
    try{
        conn.close();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Then I have my code which is just trying to select everything from the table.
I have created the table in msAccess and the code seems to get through the connect method in the above code without any problems, indicating it is finding the database and accessing it somewhat. The problem happens when I call the prepareStatement using the connection, i.e. code line:

```
stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

The full code is:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Program2{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            // Load the JDBC driver
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();

        // Establishing db connection
        Connection conn = AccessDBConnect.connect();

        // Displaying all records from employee file
        System.out.println("Display records of all employees");
        display(conn);

        // Closing the connection
        AccessDBConnect.closeConnection(conn);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

// Display details of all employees
public static void display(Connection conn){
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    // SQL statement
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);   // Prepare the SQL statement
        rs = stm.executeQuery();            // Execture the SQL statement

        // Navigate through the ResultSet and print
        while (rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String gender = rs.getString("gender");
            String address = rs.getString("address");

            System.out.println("ID: \t \t" + id);
            System.out.println("Name: \t \t" + name);
            System.out.println("Gender: \t" + gender);
            System.out.println("Address: \t" + address);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    // Closing the resultSet
    rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void test(){
    int a = "hello";
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the error because when you try to call `.prepareStatement` the connection is closed. Your `AccessDBConnect2` class contains a `finally` block that closes the connection before it returns. Fix that class so it leaves the connection open.

By the way, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 and is effectively obsolete. You might be interested in this alternative:

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: Thank you so much, the finally was the problem.
This was such an obvious mistake, just the type that will drive you crazy for hours and hours.
I will have a look at the alternative to the JDBC-ODBC in Java 8.
Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I've removed the obviously incorrect answer :) another possibility:

I would think the issue is in your connection to the database, try changing 'C:/Users/Bridget/Documents/EmployeeSys.accdb'
 to
 'C:\\Users\Bridget\Documents\EmployeeSys.accdb'

Comment: No, "Values can be retrieved using either the index number of the column or the name of the column." (ref: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html))

Comment: Thanks for your help but my problem is before I get to this statement. It is at the first statement inside the try block:
stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: sorry that was a bit of a lazy answer above!, I should've known that - I would think the issue is in your connection to the database, try changing 'C:/Users/Bridget/Documents/EmployeeSys.accdb' to 'C:\\Users\Bridget\Documents\EmployeeSys.accdb'

Comment: Sorry, strike two. Paths with forward slashes like `C:/Users/ ...` work just fine.

Comment: Time for me to find a new hobby it seems... :)